# Writing Python Script`s Results into Text file

Tags: python

I am trying to write my below pinging script results into a Text file, but i got an error message.

Below is my code:

```py
import os
import time
import subprocess


# Open file for saving ping results
results_file = open("results.txt", "w")

with open('ip-source.txt') as IPs:
    hosts = IPs.read()
    hosts = hosts.splitlines()
    for ip in hosts:
        os.system('cls')
        print('Printing now:', ip)
        print('-'*60)
        result = os.system('ping -n 4 {}'.format(ip))
        print('-'*60)
        time.sleep(1)

with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as output:
    output.write("\n".join([post.text for post in result]))
```

and when i ran it i got below error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 21, in <module>
output.write("\n".join([post.text for post in result]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: what is the type of result?

Comment: take a look at what `os.system` returns, it is not the console output, but rather the exit signal (0,1)

Comment: `result` containing int data. can you please print `result`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Comment: i printed the output of 'result' it is 0-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better to open the output file once, then have each of the subprocesses append to it as you go.

```py
with open('ip-source.txt') as IPs, open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    for ip in IPs:
        subprocess.run(
            ['ping', '-n', '4', ip.rstrip('\n')],
            stdout=output, text=True, check=True)
```

Notice also how this avoids invoking a shell at all.

You could streamline this slightly by opening the output file as binary; then you can take out the `text=True` and let the file accept raw bytes (even though they are eventually going to be parsed as Unicode strings by whatever reads the text file subsequently).

In Python 3, a subprocess returns `bytes` by default; you then have to `decode` those bytes into a `str` (once you know their encoding); or you can specify `text=True` to have Python transparently encode and decode all these bytes as strings, using the default encoding (UTF-8 on any adult system; YMMV on Windows).

Comment: How can exclude those ping results with ``Request timed out.`` or ``destination unreachable`` because it causes a problem later in analysis

Comment: Then you can't write directly to the file, or maybe you'll want to `grep -v -e 'Request timed out' -e 'destination unreachable' file` and take it from there. To filter them out while Python is reading, use `result = subprocess.run(..., capture=True)` and loop over `result.stdout.splitlines()` to filter out the ones you don't want. This isn't hard to find from the `subprocess` documentation; ask a new question if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` returns the exit signal (typically `0` or `1`) from the process called. If you look, `os.system` is actually just a wrapper function for `subprocess.Popen`.

You'll want to a) use something like `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.check_output` and then b) add results to a list:

```py
import subprocess
...
results = []
for ip in hosts:
    ...
    results.append(str(subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-n", "4", str(ip)])))

with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as output:
    output.writelines(results)
```

Comment: Unfortunatuly i got below error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 23, in <module>
    output.writelines(results)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: You can fix that with `text=True` but I'll post a separate answer with more details.

Comment: @AhmedM. Just convert the output to a `str` object then

Comment: Lovely bro, it worked after converted the output to str! Thanks!